# Vectorizing words to use a Machine Learning algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, words

I'm testing an idea to vectorize any secuence of symbols into fixed size vector in R^n using a hierarchical combination of echo state networks. The objective is to classify these sequences as vector (there is a lot of Machine Learning algorithms to use with fixed sized real vectors).

In particular, i'm testing this algorithm with english words, trying to classify them as nouns or adjectives. My dataset is here: http://www.ashley-bovan.co.uk/words/partsofspeech.html

Using a SVM to classify, i'm getting 9% of error, somebody please can point me to relevant papers or results to compare?

Thanks!

Comment: Nice example -- but 90 % seems to be a universal constant. Could you post some of the mis-classified words ? What's n, how do you normalize the n-vectors ?

Answer (score 0):

Several years ago I worked on algorithm which used Markov Chains to classify strings as correct russian words or some random strings (without using of any dictionary). Here is link to the translated article:

http://www.begellhouse.com/journals/2b6239406278e43e,685626ff507e6e58,5232ec7f32b362ef.html

I obtained result around 91% (very similar to those you got for your problem which I find very fascinating). During my research I came across another study where authors tried to classify a phrase (string consisting of at least three words) as english, french or german. They had a bit lower success rate (~80%). I can't find a link to their work on internet but it was called something like  - Murray "Probabilistic language modelling"

Comment: If you remember where i can find some of these dataset to test, it will be interesting to compare it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How are you using the SVM to classify? Which formulation - c-svm, nu-svm, etc? SVM is very sensitive to its parameters. Which kernel are you using? What parameters for the kernel are you using? Value of C/nu?

The right parameters will vary by dataset and in general part of the data is used to find the best combination of kernel & parameters.  The wrong combination can easily throw your results off significantly.  Perhaps you have already done this, it just isn't clear from what you said and can make a big difference.

Comment: I'm using c-svm (in python with mdp, which is based on libsvm). The  kernel is linear but i don't really adjust the parameters given by libsvm, i'm just using the defaults (c = 1 according to the libsvm documentation) because i want to do quick test and to know how far it is from the state of the art.

Comment: Unfortunately SVM isn't a good 'quick test' classifier - to get good results you need to tune the parameters. I recommend reading [A Practical Guide to Support Vector Classication by Chih-Wei Hsu](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf), Chih-Chung Chang, and Chih-Jen Lin. It goes over how to make sure your data is scaled correctly and you've tuned the parameters well. If you got 91% accuracy with no tuning, its likely you could do much better.

Comment: In terms of determining state of the art - my research isn't in that area so I don't know offhand, but a quick [google scholar search](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%22parts+of+speech%22+tag&btnG=Search&as_sdt=0%2C22&as_ylo=&as_vis=0) reveals this paper: [Transformation-Based Error-Driven
Learning and Natural Language Processing: A Case Study in
Part-of-Speech Tagging](http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/J/J95/J95-4004.pdf) with over 1500 citations. They claim a 99% accuracy, though I only skimmed it. Start there and look at papers which cited this paper to find more recent work.